# erlang - return time in utc format

Tags: erlang

How to return time in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) format (2014-06-01T12:00:00Z). I read docs about calendar module, but there was no explanation how to generate time format like this. My program should work in different time zones, so please give me advices.

Answer (score 2):

The Erlang Central page [Converting Between struct:time and ISO8601 Format](https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/Converting_Between_struct:time_and_ISO8601_Format) has this example:

> Unfortunately, no Erlang libraries provide this functionality. Luckily, the native Erlang date and time formats are very easy to format for display or transmission, even in ISO-8601 format:
>
> ```
> -module(iso_fmt).
> -export([iso_8601_fmt/1]).
>
> iso_8601_fmt(DateTime) ->
>     {{Year,Month,Day},{Hour,Min,Sec}} = DateTime,
>     io_lib:format("~4.10.0B-~2.10.0B-~2.10.0B ~2.10.0B:~2.10.0B:~2.10.0B",
>         [Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Sec]).
>
> format_iso8601() ->
>     {{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Min, Sec}} =
>         calendar:universal_time(),
>     iolist_to_binary(
>       io_lib:format(
>         "~.4.0w-~.2.0w-~.2.0wT~.2.0w:~.2.0w:~.2.0wZ",
>         [Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Sec] )).
> ```
>
> Using the above module:
>
> ```
> 1> {{Year,Month,Day},{Hour,Min,Sec}} = erlang:localtime().
> {{2004,8,28},{1,19,37}}
> 2> io:fwrite("~s\n",[iso_fmt:iso_8601_fmt(erlang:localtime())]).
> 2004-08-28 01:48:48
> ```

To make it output time in UTC, just pass it the return value of `erlang:universaltime()` instead of `erlang:localtime()`.

Comment: io:fwrite("~s\n",[iso_fmt:iso_8601_fmt(erlang:localtime())]). this prints ok and  2004-08-28 01:48:48. i am converting time in binary so i don't want ok in my result

Comment: ok is the return value of the io:fwrite ([link](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fwrite-2)) function. In erlang all functions have a return value. The fact that you see it in the shell is just because the io:fwrite is the last function in your test case. But if you need to get the result in order to convert it, you have to use io_lib:fwrite ([link](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#fwrite-2)) which return the string rather the print it and return ok.